# How does the meta reputation work?

Tags: support

I've just entered the meta and saw that I have 20 reputation less than my reputation on the main site, (3108 vs. 3088).

I thought that the rep in meta is equal to the rep on the main site, and that meta posts don't add rep, but apparently I'm wrong. How does the meta reputation work?

(I know that I couldn't get 3088 rep on the meta alone, as I din't have enough posts for this).

Comment: They are the same but the amount is synced once in a while. My bet is that your rep just increased on main. It reads at 3108 as I am answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reputation is synced every hour from the main site to meta, so the meta site lags behind if you have recent changes in reputation.